# Need to "group" records but I don't have an aggregate function

Tags: sql-server, grouping, sql-server-2014

I have a table called "Payments" as follows:

```
+----+--------+
| ID | Amount |
+----+--------+
|  1 | 1.00   |
|  2 | 3.00   |
|  3 | -15.00 |
|  3 | 20.00  |
+----+--------+
```

"Amount" represents cash that changes hands - a record with a positive amount indicates cash taken in and a record with a negative amount indicates cash returned as change.

The following query:

```
SELECT ID
     , CASE WHEN Amount >= 0 THEN Amount END AS CashTaken
     , CASE WHEN Amount < 0 THEN Amount END AS CashBack  
  FROM Payments
 WHERE TicketID IN ('1', '2', '3')
```

...gives me this result set:

```
+----+-----------+----------+
| ID | CashTaken | CashBack |
+----+-----------+----------+
|  1 | 1.00      | NULL     |
|  2 | 3.00      | NULL     |
|  3 | NULL      | -15.00   |
|  3 | 20.00     | NULL     |
+----+-----------+----------+
```

How can I group these records by ID so that I can get the following?

```
+----+-----------+----------+
| ID | CashTaken | CashBack |
+----+-----------+----------+
|  1 | 1.00      | NULL     |
|  2 | 3.00      | NULL     |
|  3 | 20.00     | -15.00   |
+----+-----------+----------+
```

I'm a little embarrassed, because I feel like this is something very simple that is right in front of my face.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can you try with `MIN`, `MAX`:

```
SELECT TicketID 
     , MAX(CASE WHEN Amount >= 0 THEN Amount END) AS CashTaken
     , MIN(CASE WHEN Amount < 0 THEN Amount END) AS CashBack  
FROM Payments
WHERE TicketID IN ('1', '2', '3')
GROUP BY TicketID
```

Sample execution with given data:

```
DECLARE @Payments TABLE (TicketID INT, Amount DECIMAL(5,2));

INSERT INTO @Payments(TicketID, Amount) 

SELECT 1, 1.00 UNION
SELECT 2, 3.00 UNION
SELECT 3, -15.00 UNION
SELECT 3, 20.00;

SELECT TicketID
     , MAX(CASE WHEN Amount >= 0 THEN Amount END) AS CashTaken
     , MIN(CASE WHEN Amount < 0 THEN Amount END) AS CashBack  
FROM @Payments
WHERE TicketID IN ('1', '2', '3')
GROUP BY TicketID
```

Result:

```
TicketID    CashTaken   CashBack
---------------------------------
1           1.00       NULL
2           3.00       NULL
3           20.00     -15.00
```

Comment: I knew that it was something simple that I was overlooking. I am ultimately joining this query to my outer query. I forgot that you could have multiple aggregate functions in a single query. My Payments table also has a "RecordCreationDate" field - I needed the MAX(Date) by ID and I was able to slip that into this same query. Thank you!